# Why does the diff on this suggested edit make it look like the editor destroyed the answer?

Tags: support, specific-edit, diff

I just reviewed [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29966709) that moved some Python code out of a runnable snippet. It's obviously a good edit, so I approved it.

But before I approved it, I checked the diff; it helps me spot where someone may have accidentally deleted something in making a change like this. But the diff here makes no sense to me. It looks like it's saying the editor deleted a bunch of the code and not just the tags for the snippet.

Shouldn't it have two more sections that say "*n* identical lines skipped" instead of striking out all of the code?

Comment: At least we can be sure that people didn't blindly reject the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They did delete a bunch of code, because OP actually had the code in their question *twice* (in nested snippets as well) as shown in the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/e05cabb2-b49b-4c01-957a-f8debd6768dc/view-source).

The edit in the suggestion removes the tags for *both* of the snippets and one of the sets of code, leaving the other intact.